# facebook graph api integration with java app

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I have a java application which uses restfb 1.6.11.jar, but since old rest fb became absolute, and we need to use graph api, 
so my question is, does the upgrading the restfb jar to latest version and creating new app under facebook developer should be the way to go?
has anyone done this type of exercise before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that should be fine. Make sure you are using the latest version of RestFB (currently 1.12.0) and you should also use the latest version of the Facebook Graph API (v2.3) to make sure that your application will continue to work for as long as possible.